# Setting up codeship to deploy bitbucket repository to vidahost cloud hosting

Tags: continuous-integration, cloud-hosting, continuous-deployment, codeship

I have a private bitbucket php project repository, codeship account and a vidahost cloud hosting. How to implement continuous integration and deployment? What is the workflow to achieve this? I did googling but could not find complete tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Ahoy Dipendra,

Marko from the Codeship crew here. Could you send me an in app message with a link to your project, so I can take a look at your current setup and help get you started?

As for deploying to Vidahost, you have multiple options. You could use a tool like Capistrano (or Mina, or something similar in your preferred programming language) or you could use SCP or FTP directly to copy your files. For the latter option, please see our documentation at https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-ftp-sftp-scp/. (You'll find documentation on Capistrano and a bunch of other deployment options via this link as well.)

I'll update this answer with more specific details, once I know more about your setup!

Cheers, 
Marko